# how to find video and audio stream times without the deprecated values? Fork: libav 10.5

Tags: visual-c++, codec, libav

After looking into the documentation, AVStream.pts has been deprecated. Before I was using this loop to try and get the video and audio time. it's the same as whats in the api-example.c (which no longer works):

```
if (audioStream_)
    {
        VideoTime = (double)videoStream_->pts.val*videoStream_->time_base.num/videoStream_->time_base.den;
        do
        {
            AudioTime = (double)audioStream_->pts.val*audioStream_->time_base.num/audioStream_->time_base.den;
            ret = WriteAudioFrame();
        }
        while (AudioTime < VideoTime && ret);
        if (ret < 0)
            return ret;
    }
```

what is the current alternative? I haven't been able to get anything to work as of yet and I've been searching for around 3 hours.

Answer (score 1):

According to [`doc/APIchanges`](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob_plain;f=doc/APIchanges;hb=HEAD):

> 2014-05-19 - 999a99c / a312f71 - lavf 55.38.101 / 55.17.1 - `avformat.h`
>   Deprecate `AVStream.pts` and the `AVFrac` struct, which was its only use
>   case. Use `av_stream_get_end_pts()`.

I don't know where you got `api-example.c`, but that has been moved to `doc/examples/decoding_encoding.c` (I'm referring to code from the current git master branch).

Comment: I've found the encoding_decoding.c but it doesn't talk about how to interleave the audio/video from what I can tell. Am I missing something?
I got it from https://libav.org/download.html 2 weeks ago. the libav V10 "Eks"

Comment: Oh, you're using libav (the fork, while I assumed you meant libav* the libraries from FFmpeg). I don't know anything about this fork. I wish people wouldn't use the [tag:ffmpeg] tag for forks, and I wish this fork didn't use such a damned confusing name.

Comment: ah, I see what you mean, sorry, I can take the tag off.

Comment: You're using Libav (the fork), but referring to documentation and examples from FFmpeg. Additionally you're probably mixing information and examples from API incompatible versions.

Comment: I see what you mean, sorry about that, I'll clean it up a bit. new to libav